# When are parenthesis required when accessing something like &variable->member?

Tags: c, pointers

I m a novice in C programming and would like to know whether the following are equivalent:

```
&clockA->tick_time
```

and

```
&(clockA->tick_time)
```

Is there any effect of parenthesis here?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they are equivalent. As a general rule of C language, *postfix* operators always have higher precedence than *prefix* (unary) operators, which means that there's no need to parenthesize the postfix part.

So, for example, in expression `(&clockA)->tick_time` parenthesis does make a difference - it gives unary `&` higher "priority" than that of postfix `->`. But in your example it is superfluous.